Stimulus reflex is not rendering values correctly after execution ruby 3, stimulus 3.4.1 and rails 6
I am working on stimulus reflex guide Quick Start, they are implementing a simple incremental using stimulus reflex. Every thing is working perfectly but still value of count is incrementing after page reload not by clinking on the 'increment'.
These are the logs I have got
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
Count is 5
  Rendering pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Count in page is 5
  Rendered pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 124)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4617)


Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2024-08-30 18:52:04 +0500
StimulusReflex::Channel stopped streaming from StimulusReflex::Channel
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2024-08-30 18:52:04 +0500
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2024-08-30 18:52:04 +0500
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
StimulusReflex::Channel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
StimulusReflex::Channel is streaming from StimulusReflex::Channel
StimulusReflex::Channel#receive({"target"=>"Counter#increment", "args"=>[], "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/page/count", "attrs"=>{"href"=>"#", "data-reflex"=>"click->Counter#increment", "data-step"=>"1", "data-count"=>"5", "data-controller"=>"stimulus-reflex", "data-action"=>"click->stimulus-reflex#__perform", "checked"=>false, "selected"=>false, "tag_name"=>"A"}, "dataset"=>{"data-reflex"=>"click->Counter#increment", "data-step"=>"1", "data-count"=>"5", "data-controller"=>"stimulus-reflex", "data-action"=>"click->stimulus-reflex#__perform"}, "selectors"=>[], "reflexId"=>"2f737a01-84f4-4dba-9d66-03d87df55ad6", "resolveLate"=>false, "xpathController"=>"/html/body/a[1]", "xpathElement"=>"/html/body/a[1]", "reflexController"=>"stimulus-reflex", "permanentAttributeName"=>"data-reflex-permanent", "formData"=>""})
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
Count is 6
  Rendering pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Count in page is 6
  Rendered pages/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 12)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3253)


[ActionCable] Broadcasting to StimulusReflex::Channel: {"cableReady"=>true, "operations"=>[{"selector"=>"body", "html"=>"\n    <a href=\"#\" data-reflex=\"click-&gt;Counter#increment\" data-step=\"1\" data-count=\"6\">Increment 6</a>\n  ", "childrenOnly"=>true, "permanentAttributeName"=>"data-reflex-permanent", "stimulusReflex"=>{"target"=>"Counter#increment", "args"=>[], "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/page/count", "attrs"=>{"href"=>"#", "data-reflex"=>"click->Counter#increment", "data-step"=>"1", "data-count"=>"5", "data-controller"=>"stimulus-reflex", "data-action"=>"click->stimulus-reflex#__perform", "checked"=>false, "selected"=>false, "tagName"=>"A"}, "dataset"=>{"data-reflex"=>"click->Counter#increment", "data-step"=>"1", "data-count"=>"5", "data-controller"=>"stimulus-reflex", "data-action"=>"click->stimulus-reflex#__perform"}, "selectors"=>["body"], "reflexId"=>"2f737a01-84f4-4dba-9d66-03d87df55ad6", "resolveLate"=>false, "xpathController"=>"/html/body/a[1]", "xpathElement"=>"/html/body/a[1]", "reflexController"=>"stimulus-reflex", "permanentAttributeName"=>"data-reflex-permanent", "formData"=>"", "morph"=>:page}, "operation"=>"morph"}], "version"=>"5.0.5"}

[35ad736b] 1/1 CounterReflex#increment -> body via Page Morph (morph)

StimulusReflex::Channel transmitting {"cableReady"=>true, "operations"=>[{"selector"=>"body", "html"=>"\n    <a href=\"#\" data-reflex=\"click-&gt;Counter#increment\" data-step=\"1\" data-count=\"6\">Increment 6</a>\n  ", "childrenOnly"=>true, "permanentAttributeName"=>"data-reflex-permanent", "stimulusReflex"=>{"target"=>"Counter#i... (via streamed from StimulusReflex::Channel)


Cannot figure out where is the problem
I just want to test stimulus reflex by using simple code
